# Why to use $ sign at the end of the sheet name when using Excel sheet to retrieve the value?

Tags: c#, .net

why to use $ sign at the end of the sheet name when usign Excel sheet to retrieve the value. For Example if i am writting OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]", ocon); what is the purpose behind adding that '$' sign at the end of the sheet name?

Comment: I think this question would be better on SU, as you are looking for an answer about how to use Excel.  Also I don't understand why you have taged it C# and .net

Comment: Sorry Ian, but this is clearly SO to me, because he is automating Excel from his C# code (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]", ocon);).

Comment: Mr Ian, U got it wrong actually. Since the question is related to the way the query is written in the OledbDataAdapter, i tagged it with c# and .net. And if i m not wrong this class is available with c# and related to .net. correct?

Comment: by the same logic a CSS quesions could be tagged c# you are are using asp.net to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The '$' sign separates the sheet name from the table name. A sheet can contain multiple tables. Leaving the space behind the '$' empty says your using the sheet directly and not only a table on it.

Comment: this is making somewhat sense, but if thats the case then again a question raises that can u connect to sqlDB using this oledbDataAdapter? And again as we have specified the DataProvider in the connection string explicitly as Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, there isnt necessity to distinguish them i feel.